# Recurrent Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider the following theorem from Durrett's book. In the last part of the proof he deduced that $P_y(X_n \in F \text{ i.o.})=1$ and since $F$ is finite then $P_y(X_n=x \text{ i.o.})=1$ for a $x \in F.$

I can't see how he deduced from for all $x \notin F,P_x(\tau<\infty)=1$ that $P_y(X_n \in F \text{ i.o.})=1$ and that since $F$ is finite then $P_y(X_n=x \text{ i.o.})=1$ for a $x \in F.$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point is just iteration and the Markov property: each time the chain leaves $F$, it will return with probability one, so (intersecting countably many events of probability 1) it will return to $F$ infinitely often almost surely.

The second point is a case of the pigeonhole principle: If the chain visits $F$ infinitely often, and $F$ is finite, then at least one of the states in $F$ must be visited infinitely often.